# does the soql support passrole or assumerole?

Tags: soql, authentication, accesstoken

1. our salesforce is SSO login, so means we don't know the users' credentials, but we can get the SFDC auth token and user profiles
2. need to run the SOQL as the logged-in user, the hierarchy, the limitation, the audit logs, etc.
3. the SOQL would be run in the BFF, not directly on the client-side.

> e.g. the end-user click some button on the client, the request will
> go BFF, then BFF run the SOQL as the logged-in user, then respond to
> the client.

Comment: What is the context of the SOQL? If Apex, see the existing answer from CasperHarmer. If REST API it already applies permissions and sharing considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Something very similar is currently in Beta - [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm)

Basically you can write a query that will return results that correspond with the level of access that the running user has.

This not related to sharing, but to the access the user has to the objects and fields being queried.

The keyword is `WITH USER_MODE` eg:

```
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState FROM Account WITH USER_MODE];
```

If the running user isn't allowed to see `BillingState`, then that field will be missing from the results.